# Linux NSwag NPM CLI-framework Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.0 was not found

Tags: linux, .net-core, mono, fedora, nswag

Even after setting `nswag version /runtime:NetCore31` the command `nswag help` and others throws the following error:

> NSwag NPM CLI It was not possible to find any compatible framework
>   version The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not
>   found.
>     - The following frameworks were found:
>         3.1.3 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>
> You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework
>   and/or SDK.
>
> The specified framework can be found at:
>     - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.1.0&arch=x64&rid=fedora.30-x64
>   child_process.js:660
>       throw err;
>       ^

```
Error: Command failed: dotnet "/usr/lib/node_modules/nswag/bin/binaries/NetCore21/dotnet-nswag.dll" help
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/nswag/bin/nswag.js:69:11
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:286:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:659:12) {
  status: 150,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 10831,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

I wonder if NSwag requires 2.1.0 or if it's a wrong environment setup (Linux/Fedora 30)

Answer (score 0):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233865/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-net-core-side-by-side-on-ubuntu), [wiki.archlinux.org/.NET_Core](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/.NET_Core) and [this issue](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/1359), it worked with the following steps:

```sh
dotnet --list-sdks
```

> 3.1.201 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

Install required .NET version **(worked only on the same folder as current SDK)**

```sh
./dotnet-install.sh -Version 2.1.805 --install-dir /usr/share/dotnet
```

Then set runtime, as described on [NSwag tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nswag)

```sh
nswag version /runtime:NetCore31
```