# when i open unity and make something project then the error is coming that " no usable version of libssl was found "

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

i am new to linux ubuntu . i am using ubuntu 22.04 . recently i downloaded unity and it is showing error " no usable version of libssl was found "  How to fix this PLease help me !!
i tried to find solution for this problem and i found nothing .
( i am using linux and i am new to linux )
.

Comment: Found a forum post from yesterday [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/workaround-for-libssl-issue-on-ubuntu-22-04.1271405/)  regarding this.

Answer (score 46):

You need to download the missing libssl library and install it

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```

Comment: This link no longer works, however you can visit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/ and select the relevant download to your machine.
Downloading and installing libssl from here worked, but strangly not from `sudo apt install libssl-dev`.

Comment: I've just updated the link

Answer (score 17):

**For Ubuntu**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rael-gc/rvm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Comment: This actually worked on my Linux Mint 21 setup with Unity.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install libssl1.1

```
# download package with wget
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb

# install package locally
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

original gist post:

https://gist.github.com/joulgs/c8a85bb462f48ffc2044dd878ecaa786

Comment: For anyone looking to solve this for Unity Compilation, this helped me get a succesful Android Build (target API 30) compiled on Ubuntu 22.10 with Unity 2020.3.43f1. IL2CPP and .NET 4.x

Comment: Great! I tried this in Pop_os!, Unity 2021.3.22f1 and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this error lies in **incompatible versions** of **Open ssl** on your machine and needed from Unity. Ubuntu 22.04 installs **Open ssl 3.0** per default but Unity for Linux currently uses **.Net5** per default and therefore can only run with ***Open ssl 1.0 or 1.1***.

To fix this, you need to downgrade your Open ssl on your machine to either 1.0 or 1.1. I tested 1.0.2 version from the [link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/) Jeff Chen commented below rainman's answer.

I also tested the wget method from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1094690/1604061) over on askubuntu just with the downloaded package and it worked like a charm for me.

Unity is aware of this problem as seen [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/workaround-for-libssl-issue-on-ubuntu-22-04.1271405/#post-8098841).

Edit: I had to restart my computer for the error to disappear.

Comment: I tried this and restarted and when I do `openssl version -v` it tells mw `OpenSSL 1.0.2 22 Jan 2015` but I **still** get the same error in Unity

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the openssl 1.1

Download and Install it by the following steps:

```
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1q
sudo ./config
sudo make install 

openssl version -v
```

I'm not sure but you can set `ln` too:

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
```

and if you get this error:

```
openssl: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

fix it with this command: `ldconfig` after install

Answer (score 1):

The problem doenst exist with Unity 2022.2.2.
Works great on Ubuntu 22.04 with libssl3
Unity 2021 doesnt work on same system because of libssl3