# libpq-dev python3-dev couldnot install in ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: python, ubuntu

sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-dev is already the newest version (3.10.6-1).
python3-dev set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 14.5-1ubuntu1) but 15.1-1.pgdg22.10+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108697/when-i-open-unity-and-make-something-project-then-the-error-is-coming-that-no/73066454#73066454

Comment: Can you see the link please ?

Comment: This is not my problem solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall the libpq5 with the correct version required by libpq-dev.

```
sudo apt install libpq5=14.5-1ubuntu1
```

Then try to install the libpq-dev.