# Issue running Unreal Engine 5.0.3 - No usable version of libssl was found

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I just installed `Unreal Engine 5.0.3` in `Ubuntu 22.04` and had the error

> No usable version of libssl was found

when trying to run the template with `C++`

Comment: This [thread for unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72108697/when-i-open-unity-and-make-something-project-then-the-error-is-coming-that-no) also shows solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by running `sudo apt install libssl-dev`
or

```
$ wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
```